# Python docstring search - similar to MATLAB `lookup` or Linux `apropos`

Tags: python

Is there a way to perform keyword searching of module and function docstrings *from the interpreter?*

Often, when I want to do something in Python, I know there's a module that does what I want, but I don't know what it's called. I would like a way of searching for *"the name of the function or module that does X"* without having to Google *"python do X"*.

Take the example of "how can I open an URL"? At a Linux shell, I might try `>> apropos open url`. Under MATLAB, I might try `>> lookup open url`. Both of these would give me listings of functions or modules that include the words 'open' and 'URL' somewhere in their man page or doc string. For example:

```
urllib.urlopen   : Create a file-like object for the specified URL to read from.
urllib2.urlopen  : ...
...
```

I'd like something that searches through all installed modules, not just the modules that have been `import`ed into my current session.

*Yes, Google is a great way to search Python doc strings, but the latency is a bit high. ;)*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The built-in support for that comes from `pydoc.apropos`:

```
import pydoc
pydoc.apropos('Zip')
# output: zipimport - zipimport provides support for importing Python modules from Zip archives.
```

Which, as you can see, is nearly useless. It also stops working whenever a module cannot be imported, which might mean 'always' depending on your package management style.

An alternative that I haven't used but looks promising is [apropos.py](https://github.com/philippp/apropos.py):

> Deep, dirty, and exhaustive 'apropos' for Python. Crawls all 
>   libraries in the system.path, and matches a querystring against all
>   module names, as well as class, function, and method names  and
>   docstrings of the top-level modules.
>
> Usage: ./apropos.py
>
> This module was created due to the limits of PyDoc's apropos method,
>   which fails hard when one of the top level modules cannot be imported.
>   The native apropos method also does not crawl docstrings, or deep
>   module names, which this module does.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following command:

```
pydoc -k
```

Comment: // , +1. Would you please show an example of when it's working? I've never used `pydoc` before, and it would help me to know what to expect.